# How to confirm that the differences between clusters are statistically significant?

Tags: clustering, python, computational-statistics

I have a DataFrame of page navigation behavior from visits to an e-commerce website. My independent variable is `Revenue`, which is simply binary (1 for Revenue generated in given visit, 0 for no revenue generated). Let's call the df `shopping_explore`. Some feature names include `ProductRelated`, `ProductRelated_Duration`, `Informational`, `Informational_Duration`. For instance, on a given visit, this visitor saw 5 pages related to a product, spend 10 minutes on these pages, 3 pages on product information, spend 4 minutes on these pages, and generated revenue.

I then use 3 k-means clusters (based on highest silhouette score) to separate the data into what I've interpreted as 3 groups of differing sizes: standard customer visits (some revenue, some no revenue), high-value customer visits (high proportion of revenue vs. no revenue), and low-value customer visits (hardly any revenue).

My questions are:

1. How can I confirm that the difference in clusters are statistically significant, not simply created by chance? i.e. is the high-value cluster actually a trend that can be used for grouping future customer visits with similar visiting habits, or could future visits potentially have similar behavior but a completely different ratio of revenue vs. no revenue?
2. If I should use statistical tests for this, does it matter that most of the features have extreme outliers and skewed distributions? I scaled the data before using k-means and then reversed the scale to original after performing the clustering.

Comment: Variable scaling can still totally screw your results.
Make sure to not use your target variable in clustering; and compare your results to a trivial model that only uses the length of the visit - a longer visit is more likely to lead to revenue, I guess. Rather than testing for significance, I'd rather consider how you would *use* the insights, and then devise an AB test scenario for the usage.

Comment: Interesting, I've always heard that it's crucial to scale your features for clustering. You disagree? It definitely clusters differently without scaling, but I can't tell if it's for the better or worse.

Comment: Definitely it matters. But people always assume it's sufficient to apply either normalization or standardization; whereas usually neither is optimal. How would you test which scaling is "significant"? Once you need scaling, you become completely heuristic, and any "significance" you'd get would always need the explanation "significant, but assuming that my guess at scaling variables was right".